# CryptUIWizDigitalSign failing when pwszTimestampURL specified

Tags: windows, pinvoke, code-signing, authenticode

I am having issues when calling [CryptUIWizDigitalSign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to programatically sign an executable with our public code signing certificate, without showing any UI. The certificate is a Comodo code signing certificate.

It works fine when the timestamp URL parameter is set to null, but whenever I pass anything other than null in, the call fails (returns zero).

The problem is that without a timestamp, there is no countersignature, and so there are signature validity problems further down the line.

Environment is Windows 7 x64. There is a working standard internet connection. It appears from sniffing the network traffic that no attempt is made by `CryptUIWizDigitalSign` to contact the timestamp server.

I am calling this from .NET via a PInvoke, but I doubt that would make any difference.

Not a lot on the net about this function...

```
Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2("mycert.pfx", "password")
Dim pSigningCertContext As IntPtr = cert.Handle

Dim digitalSignInfo As CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_INFO 
    = New CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_INFO
digitalSignInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(digitalSignInfo)
digitalSignInfo.dwSubjectChoice = CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_SUBJECT_FILE
digitalSignInfo.pwszFileName = "C:\temp\installer.exe"
digitalSignInfo.dwSigningCertChoice = CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_CERT
digitalSignInfo.pSigningCertContext = pSigningCertContext
digitalSignInfo.pwszTimestampURL = "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode"
digitalSignInfo.dwAdditionalCertChoice = 0
digitalSignInfo.pSignExtInfo = IntPtr.Zero

If (Not CryptUIWizDigitalSign(CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI, IntPtr.Zero, vbNullString, 
                              digitalSignInfo, pSignContext)) Then
    Throw New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), 
        "CryptUIWizDigitalSign")
End If
```

The CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_INFO type is defined as:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_INFO
    Public dwSize As Int32
    Public dwSubjectChoice As Int32
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> Public pwszFileName As String
    Public dwSigningCertChoice As Int32
    Public pSigningCertContext As IntPtr
    Public pwszTimestampURL As String
    Public dwAdditionalCertChoice As Int32
    Public pSignExtInfo As IntPtr
End Structure

Public Const CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_SUBJECT_FILE As Int32 = 1
Public Const CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_CERT As Int32 = 1
Public Const CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI As Int32 = 1
```

Comment: Maybe `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` may help debugging this?

Comment: Please show the p/invoke declaration of `CryptUIWizDigitalSign`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - works only within a 32 bit process.

Comment: Any idea why? Is that to say that 64-bit processes just aren't allowed to access the crypto API? Because that sounds...wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You've applied the `MarshalAs` attribute on `pwszFileName` but not `pwszTimestampURL`, is there any reason for this? They're described identically in the [documentation for CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

pwszFileName:

> A pointer to a null-terminated Unicode string that contains the path and file name of the file to sign. This member is used if CRYPTUI_WIZ_DIGITAL_SIGN_SUBJECT_FILE is specified for the dwSubjectChoice member.

pwszTimestampURL:

> A pointer to a null-terminated Unicode string that contains the URL for the time stamp.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem for me, and this fix worked.  I am using this from IIS (Win 2003), but I have IIS forced to run as a 32-bit process, so cannot confirm it works on 64-bit.